# Maximum of integration of function over multivariate gaussian w. r. t. mean parameter

Tags: probability, integration, optimization, gaussian

Suppose a function $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ that takes an unique maximum at $x_0$ (and is sufficiently well-behaved, e. g. Continuos) Suppose that for a fixed $\Sigma$, for all $\mu$, $ g(\mu) := \int f \ \mathcal{N} (\mu, \Sigma) < \infty$

Intuitively, I would suppose that $g$ takes a (unique) maximum at $x_0$, but I don't know how one would prove this.

Under which conditions is the above true? How could i prove it?

Edit:

Based on the above comments, some thoughts:

Let $h$ be nonnegative, decreasing, with unique maximum at $x_0$.

Furhtermore, let $f(x) = h((x-x_0)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x-x_0))$.

Then 
$ g(\mu) =  \int h((x-x_0)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x-x_0)) exp( (x-\mu)^T \Sigma^{-1} (x-\mu)) dx$

$= \int h((y^T\Sigma^{-1}y) exp( (y - (\mu - x_0)^T \Sigma^{-1} (y-(\mu-x_0)) dy$

By substitution. Assuming we can pull the derivative inside of the integral, we get
$ \frac{\partial g}{\partial \mu} (\mu) =\int 2y^T\Sigma^{-1}(\mu-x_0) h((y^T\Sigma^{-1}y) exp( (y - (\mu - x_0)^T \Sigma^{-1} (y-(\mu-x_0)) dy$.

Clearly, this has a zero at $x_0$. 
But if we now evaluate the Hessian at $x_0$, it reads
$\frac{\partial g}{\partial \mu \partial \mu^T}(x_0) = \int 2 y^T \Sigma^{-1} h((y^T\Sigma^{-1}y) exp( (y^T \Sigma^{-1} y) dy \\ 
= \int 2 (\Sigma^{-\frac{1}{2}}y)^T \Sigma^{\frac{1}{2}} \Sigma^{-1} h((y^T\Sigma^{-1}y) exp( (y^T \Sigma^{-1} y) dy\\ $
Substituting again, we get
$\\  \int 2 u \Sigma^{-\frac{1}{2} } h(u^Tu) exp(u^Tu) = 0 $ because this is an odd function. So this does not help us deciding on whether this is a maximum..

**Edit 2 - Proof for bowl-shaped functions**

Apparently, in the situation where $h$ is "bowl-shaped" (that means the sublevel sets $K_c = \{x| h(x) \leq c\}$ are symmetric and convex) there is a proof for the above assumption. The result is known as "Andersons Lemma" and a nice (and not very involved) proof can be found [here](http://www.stat.yale.edu/~yw562/teaching/598/lec09.pdf) .

Comment: Do you think  $g$ is a differentiable function? How would you do it if it were the case? (Keeping you dream derivative candidate as the actual candidate)

Comment: Do you imply pulling the derivative into the integral? Such that we end up with $  \mu  \int f(x) \mathcal{N}(x,\mu,\Sigma) dx  - \int x f  \mathcal{N}(x,\mu,\Sigma) dx  = 0 $ ? I still would not know how to proceed then with the integral on the right

Comment: The counterexample below shows that your guess is incorrect, the reason essentially being that even though there is a global maximum, heavy decay around the maximum accompanied by a large enough disjoint patch taking values consistently close to the global maximum, will not let $g$ 's maximum settle at that of $f$. Therefore, heuristically, you will require (at least) two things . 1 : Around $x_0$, $f$ should not decay too fast, and 2 : at other points not in the above neighbourhood, values of $f$ should not touch $x_0$.

Comment: A trivial case of $f$ for which this will work,  is $f$ of the form $f(x) = h(\|x - x_0\|)$ where $h : [0,\infty) \to \mathbb R$ is a decreasing function. I think in this case $g$ will attain a unique maximum at $x_0$. Can you try to prove it specifically for functions of this form?

Comment: I see now with the below counterexample that I was implicitly assuming only symmetric cases or alike, but obviously the claim seems to be way to strong now based on just the local behaviour at one point...

Comment: Exactly, I am happy you have realized the issue, because it gives necessary conditions for this to hold.

Comment: So to your question, I still do not know exactly which technique to apply to prove it in this case. Maybe if $h(||x-x_0||)$ is integrable itself, one could see this as maximization of the inner product of a fixed vector and a given set (not a subspace...) - maybe one still could argue with the orthogonal projection...

Comment: Yes. I have not thought much about this question, but I would like to think about it the way you have.

Comment: Well I could still not tackle it down in this easier situation. Above I included some thoughts on using derivatives..

Comment: Sounds nice, I will try to get something useful

Answer (score 1):

I think the claim is false, the follwing is a dirty proof of this.

Lets look at $n=1$, $f(x) = \begin{cases}-ax^2&\text{if } x<0\\-\frac{x^2}{x^2+1}&\text{if }x\geq 0\end{cases}$ for some $a>0$, this is differenciable everywhere (derivative in $0$ is $0$). Then the maximum is attained at $0$ and is unique. If your claim is true, then the maximum of $g$ is attained at $0$ independently of $a$, but if you augment $a$ you decrease the value of $g(0)$, actually you can find $a$ such that $g(0)\ll -1$. Now if you look at $g(x)$ for $x\gg 0$, you can make it arbitrarily close to $-1$ for a fixed $a$, hence $g(x)\gg g(0)$.

Comment: Thanks for this counterexample! Indeed, I think I was misleaded in my assumption in the first place.

Comment: I think you can find a much better example though, with some closed forms it would be more convincing.